# Extract Commit Messages From GitHub Repository Without Downloading Project

Tags: git, github

I want to extract commit messages from various repositories on GitHub without downloading the entire repository to reduce bandwidth use, and then run

```
git log --since='last month' --pretty=format:'%h,%an,%ar,%s' > log.csv
```

Is this possible?